# ibm_db or alternative for use with python 3.1 and DB2?

Tags: python, db2

I'm trying to connect a program with embedded python 3.1.4 to a IBM DB2.
I've found the ibm_db API and got it to work with a newer version of the mentioned prog which uses python 3.3 but the customer uses the older program version featuring python 3.1.
And i can't get it working with 3.1.
Is there any trick or an alternative? Does anyone have a hint?
Have searched the net but found nothing so far.

Thx in advance,
Pierre

Comment: What did you do to build ibm_db? What are the errors?

Comment: error: Microsoft Visual C++ 9.0 is required (Unable to find vcvarsall.bat). Get it from http://aka.ms/vcpython27

Comment: The above is the error message, of course i downloaded & installed the mentioned package but with no effort.

Comment: I did exactly the same steps for python 3.3 and it worked so i'm afraid it's not compatible with python 3.1. If this is the problem i will have to find another way, maybe TCP/IP communication. Sorry for the triple post need to get used to this site.